# Angular 4.1.0 and strictNullChecks - Object is possibly 'null' in template

Tags: angular, typescript

I upgraded Angular to 4.1.0 and enabled "strictNullChecks" in my project. Now, I have a bunch of errors like this **in templates (.html)**:

> > Object is possibly 'null'

And they all refer to .html templates like this:

```
<form class="ui equal width form attached segment" [formGroup]="usrFrm">
    <h4 class="ui dividing blue header">User Name</h4>
    <div class="fields">
        <div class="required field">
            <label>Title</label>
            <select class="ui dropdown">
                <option default>&lt;select title&gt;</option>
                <option value="1">Ms.</option>
                <option value="0">Mr.</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fields">
        <div class="required field" [class.error]="usrFrm.touched && usrFrm.get('firstName').invalid">
            <label>First name</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="firstName" placeholder="First Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="field" [class.error]="usrFrm.touched && usrFrm.get('middleName').invalid">
            <label>Middle name</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="middleName" placeholder="Middle Name" />
        </div>
        <div class="required field" [class.error]="usrFrm.touched && usrFrm.get('lastName').invalid">
            <label>Last name</label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" />
        </div>
    </div>
...
```

So, is there a way to fix this without turning off the "strictNullChecks"?

Comment: TypeScript isn't type checking your Angular templates, which are just strings as far as TypeScript is concerned. I think you need to look harder at that error message.

Comment: How do you build your application? ngc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, there's an issue with Typescript for now - https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16357. So, we'll need to wait for another release.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `usrFrm.controls.firstName.invalid`. I know is another way of `getting` the invalid state but worked for me when I had the `Object is possibly 'null'` TS prompt popup.

Answer (score 0):

Change strict cheks settings:
In tsconfig.json

```
    compilerOptions:{

       "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
       "strictNullChecks":false,
       "strictPropertyInitialization": false,

     }
```